# Typescript: How to type generic higher order function

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, promise

I have the following utility function:

```js
async function resolvePromises<F extends (arg: any) => any>(
  data: Parameters<F>,
  list: F[] | F[][],
): Promise<boolean> {
  for (const item of list) {
    if (!Array.isArray(item)) {
      await item(data);

      continue;
    }

    await Promise.allSettled(item.map((action) => action(data)));
  }

  return true;
}
```

Which is instantiated like so:

```js
const wait = ({ time = 1000 }) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));

resolvePromises({ time: 2000 }, [wait, wait]);
```

I want TypeScript to only allow the "data" argument to match the provided promise based functions, so using the above example, this would error:

```js
resolvePromises({ time: 2000, name: 'John' }, [wait, wait]);
```

It's nearly there, but the first argument of `resolvePromises` always shows the following:

[image]

If I change the first argument of `resolvePromises` to an array, e.g:

```js
resolvePromises([{ time: 2000 }], [wait, wait]);
```

I correctly get errors when I add properties to the first argument that the functions do not support. The first argument of the `wait` function isn't an array though..

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my typing of `resolvePromises`, and why?

**EDIT**
This function can also be called with a nested array of Promises, e.g:

```js
resolvePromises({ time: 1000}, [[wait, wait],[wait]]);
```

Many thanks!

Comment: `Parameters<F>` will be an arraylike type, though.  Perhaps you want `Parameters<F>[0]` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/m3onLm).  But I would just make your function generic in the input and output like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXyE8N).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining when I get a chance. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Hey @jcalz, thanks for the answer. The first option works like a charm, many thanks. The second doesn't error when an unknown property or incorrect type is defined as the data argument, is there a way to tweak it so that it does? If not, no worries, the zero index on Parameters works perfectly

Comment: I've also just noticed if I used a nested array of promises, the types are no longer enforced, e.g resolvePromises({ time: 1000 }, [[wait, wait], [wait]]). Any ideas on that? Appreciate the help! :)

Comment: I don't understand what "types are no longer enforced" means, nor do I see a problem when I put it into my IDE.  If this is a followup question you might want to make a new post about it

Comment: You answered it in your.. well, answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Parameters<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) will resolve to an array-like [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types).  If `data` is of type `Parameters<F>` then you must pass an array there.

If, instead, you want `data` just to be the *first* parameter (while still using `Parameters<T>`), you can [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) it with `0`:

```
async function resolvePromises<F extends (arg: any) => any>(
  data: Parameters<F>[0], // <-- here
  list: F[] | F[][],
): Promise<boolean> {
  for (const item of list) {
    if (!Array.isArray(item)) {
      await item(data);
      continue;
    }
    await Promise.allSettled(item.map((action) => action(data)));
  }
  return true;
}
```

And now things work the way you expect:

```
const wait = ({ time = 1000 }) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
resolvePromises({ time: 2000 }, [wait, wait]); // okay
resolvePromises({ time: 2000, name: 'John' }, [wait, wait]); // error!
```

Note that the particular [excess property warning](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#excess-property-checks) you're trying to get isn't really a type safety issue and is therefore fragile.  Excess properties don't violate types (e.g., `{time: 2000, name: 'John'}` is a perfectly valid `{time: number}`); [structural typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) allows extra properties. Excess property checks are more of a linter feature than a type safety feature and you can't really rely on them happening everywhere.

The conventional way to represent your function is to make it [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the argument type `A` and return type `R` instead of the function type `F`, but this doesn't care about excess properties:

```
async function resolvePromises<A, R>(
  data: A,
  list: ((a: A) => R)[] | ((a: A) => R)[][],
): Promise<boolean> {
  for (const item of list) {
    if (!Array.isArray(item)) {
      await item(data);
      continue;
    }
    await Promise.allSettled(item.map((action) => action(data)));
  }
  return true;
}

resolvePromises({ time: 2000 }, [wait, wait]); // okay
resolvePromises({ time: 2000, name: 'John' }, [wait, wait]); // okay
```

And if you still care about excess properties you can guide inference so `A` is only inferred from `list` and not `data` using techniques described in [ms/TS#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829):

```
async function resolvePromises<A, R>(
  data: A & {},
  list: ((a: A) => R)[] | ((a: A) => R)[][],
): Promise<boolean> {
  for (const item of list) {
    if (!Array.isArray(item)) {
      await item(data);
      continue;
    }
    await Promise.allSettled(item.map((action) => action(data)));
  }
  return true;
}

resolvePromises({ time: 2000 }, [wait, wait]); // okay
resolvePromises({ time: 2000, name: 'John' }, [wait, wait]); // error
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&noErrorTruncation=true#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-SarO8weaLWGzDQgg8PnY5wOI5TnOS5ri3O5Hi7YsIGZRM3l+JtATfX9ZjBCEoRhFZgQRRwNxRR90RlYUcXRAkiRJMcYHJSkLVpPky0ZZlWQ5LkeUYhlBVI0UZkcM0Kz2S0SLlW1KLVDVCOyEN+KY80gKtHixKse1HTEN1PW9X1-WyINpKBVR4VjfAEyTVN004RCjgVW880gWBEBQH5Sy4wSaTMGsYHrNR+ibEcYAAMhzNYHH6dtXCHbte37TwfC7Edosnexp2CITcAiKJLiXXMNFXVJ0k3HI8gKcL9wPcp+GPNozwvdotxvHL-1RJ8qBfAFUIPT9UCWHC7z-foAMyejDmOM5kAuK4ryoKCnheRD4NgtqUNmfrS3BSEsWwt94XwgqpLRDEeNxCiVSoz5aNnNK6TkplqNYkVuV5AShTlHo+NBG76MU0SYCVcS-UkrUgQ+1yvpEm1frtGi1Jdd0vR9EKAYDPTkBkwygA)

Comment: This is perfect, and very informative. This actually clears up quite a bit for me, so thank you. I went with your final example as I want other engineers to be warned when the function arguments don't align. It works!